# Go to root page from a tab

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I would like to know how to go back to the rootPage defined in the `appComponent` when using tabs. The setRoot method is not working as I expected. When it is used in a Tab page the navigation stack is not cleared. On the 'home page', the back button is visible instead of the navigation toggle and the title of the tab is shown.

> By default, pages are cached and left in the DOM if they are navigated
>   away from but still in the navigation stack (the exiting page on a
>   push() for example). They are destroyed when removed from the
>   navigation stack (on pop() or setRoot()).

The statement above gives me the expectation that when I use setRoot pages are cleared from the cache. This seems to be true when it is used in a normal page but not in a tab.

In the class of the tab page, there is a function that sets the root page to home when the button is clicked.

```
goToHome() {
 this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
}
```

How can I make sure that when we are returned to the homePage there is no back button and the title of the home is used that is available in the HTML template of the component.

Comment: Could you please try by getting the `rootNav`? it'd be like `constructor(private app: App,...) {...}` and then `this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(YourPage);` If this works I'll add an answer explaining everything with more details

Comment: Thank you it works. I would appreciate the explanation.

Comment: Glad to hear that! I've added an answer with the explanation :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just like you can see in the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#tabs)

> Notice that each `<ion-tab>` binds to a `[root]` property, just like
>    in the Navigation section above. That is because each
>   `<ion-tab>` is really just a navigation controller. **This means that each
>   tab has its own history stack**, and `NavController` instances injected
>   into children `@Components` of each tab will be unique to each tab

So when setting a page as root, you're using the navigation stack from that tab, and not the one of the entire app. That's why you need to get the main navigation stack by doing:

```
constructor(private app: App,...) {...}
```

And then

```
yourMethod(): void {
    this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(YourPage);
}
```

Comment: Great Answer ... i Solved My Problem Thank you :)

Comment: Thanks sebaferreras! It saves my time.

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot !!

Comment: @YATO `getRootNav` **is not deprecated** as it still is part of the **[Ionic docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-an-overlay-component)**. There's a warning being printed in the console, but there's no information about how the new way should be used (you can check **[this post from Ionic forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/getrootnav-deprecated-use-getrootnavbyid-whats-the-value-of-the-root-nav-id/96271/38)**) to follow what Ionic team says.

Comment: The console says "(getRootNav) is deprecated and will be removed in the next major release." So it is indeed **deprecated**.

Comment: Yeah I understand that it may lead to some confusion, but Ionic team didn't provide any information on how to use the new method (it's not even included in the docs). And again, `getRootNav` **is the recommended way [to navigate from an overlay component in Ionic Docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-an-overlay-component)**.

So as of `Ionic 3.9.2` using `getRootNav` is the proper way to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

just try this it work great for me

```
this.childNavCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
```

Comment: This did not work for me but the accepted answer did